# Is there a way to get rid of the (by dot42) using community licence?

Tags: c#, android, licensing, title, dot42

I have started using the community licence of dot42 to make a small free app for android. I see the string "by dot42" in the app name, is this by design and will remain forever? or is it waiting for me to make modify some setting to remove it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the changelog of dot42 I read the following:

> Apps created with community license always get a "(by dot42.com)"
>   postfix in their application name.

Source: https://www.dot42.com/changelog.aspx @ Version 1.0.0.47, released January 15, 2013

So to answer your question, yes with the community edition, it stays because it is by design.

Answer (score 0):

As SynerCoder says, this is a restriction of the community licenses. But this will change.

In the week of 5-9 January 2015, we will release the dot42 compiler tools under the GPLv2 license. Note that GPL does not propagate to the output of GPL software. You will be able to build closed source Android applications with dot42 (including commercial). The run-time code is already licensed under Apache License 2.0: https://github.com/dot42/api. As of then, you will no longer need a Professional license to develop commercial applications with dot42. The next update of dot42 will not require activation. Also, the mentioned postfix will no longer be added.

---

UPDATE: sources are now on https://github.com/dot42

Comment: Thanks frank, since you are closely involved with do42 could you tell me is still in active development? I found a "bug" related to generics, where to report? do you still care about fixing old code bugs when your working on a different kind of dot42 now?

Comment: No, it is no longer actively developed. Hopefully it will be picked up by others after releasing the source code.